# Anything after a class definition drops an error

Tags: python, oop

I have just created a "Button" class to help me with pygame coding. I defined a method to draw the button and then done the mainloop of the module to finish the class, but anything after the definition drops a syntax error, and if I delete everything after it, it drops an Unexpected EOF error. Here is my code:

```
import pygame;
from pygame.locals import *;

frameControl = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.init;
ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((1161,303));


running = True;
ventana.fill((255,255,255));
class Button:
    def draw(self,color,size,position,Surface):
        pygame.draw.rect(Surface,color,(position,[0],position,[1],size[0],size[1])


while running:
    Button.draw((0,255,10),(50,100),(10,10),ventana)
     for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False;
    pygame.display.flip();
    frameControl.tick(30);
 pygame.quit()
```

which drops the error

`File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\gridtest.py", line 20 while running: ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

and I have this one:

```
import pygame;
from pygame.locals import *;

frameControl = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.init;
ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((1161,303));

running = True;
ventana.fill((255,255,255));
class Button:
    def draw(self,color,size,position,Surface):
        pygame.draw.rect(Surface,color,(position,[0],position,[1],size[0],size[1])

##while running:
##    Button.draw((0,255,10),(50,100),(10,10),ventana)
##     for event in pygame.event.get():
##        if event.type == QUIT:
##            running = False;
##    pygame.display.flip();
##    frameControl.tick(30);
## pygame.quit()
```

which drops the error

`File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\gridtest.py", line 25 ^ SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

Is there something I'm missing?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Count the amount of opening `(` and closing `)` on the last line of the class definition (`pygame.draw.rect`...) - you are missing a closing one

Comment: and when youre at it, remove the ; behind the input. It does not harm, but helps nothing as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to spot when you are tired, you forgot parentheses at the end of this line:

```
     pygame.draw.rect(Surface,color,(position,[0],position,[1],size[0],size[1]))
```

Comment: Oh it was that... Thank you

Comment: also, in that context, you should write "forgot", not "forget", because "forgot" is past

Comment: I'm tired too Lool ^^